# How to measure JAVA MetaSpace?

Tags: java

I am optimizing JVM parameter for a production environment, this includes setting up maximum MetaSpace for the application.I have following issues on fixing this:

1. Do I actually want to set the limit as the environment have more than one application?
2. Is there an inbuilt tool (JDK) measure the current utilization of metaspace? (as i need to connect to remote host any command line tool )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can see the utilization of metaspace memory at runtime, by running the command `jstat -gc (PID)`, where the returned result `MU` is the usage.